# Blender as Python module issues to use

Tags: python, api, blender

For test purposes,
I tried to install Blender as a Python module in a virtual environment with Python 3.7 to be sure that i can use bpy.

I follow this page for the installation (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule)

I would like at the end, when I wrote a Python script who used blender command to be able to run outside Blender software and to get information when my script finish

So I have multiples questions:

1. I don't really understand this line of command for Windows and how I can adapt to my virtual environment :

   ```
   xcopy /E bin\2.81 C:\Python37\2.81
   ```
2. I can't use 'import bpy' command even when I successfully do pip install bpy in the command line ?
3. For my final goal project, I'm afraid that it's impossible to do because I couldn't find examples or questions related to my project.
   Can someone could explain a little if it's possible or interesting to use Blender externally ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run a python script that is meant for Blender outside Blender. `The import bpy` is used to run inside the blender environment, even if you downloaded it with pip. Instead you have to run your script from Blenders python interpreter.

```
blender --debug --background --python test_blender.py
```

The python script that you launch usually should have:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
```